# How to configure indexer in Eclipse CDT to prevent indexer from blocking entire Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, indexing, eclipse-cdt, indexer

I'm using Eclipse Luna 3.8.1 CDT for c++ project containing over 730 000 lines of code. Very often indexer suspends entire application for long time, so I have to wait or even close application because working is impossible.

Are any ways to solve the problem with suspending entire Eclipse?
(Of course please don't answer like: use vim, or dive your project)

Answer (score 1):

Try improving minimum ram allocated to eclipse (`-Xms512m`).

Also go to Project `Properties -> C++ General -> Indexer` and try to disable indexer. You also have options there to enable indexer for certain categories